# Word for firm logo sign installed usually in front of building

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe the big logo sign that one normally can see in front of a headquarters building, for example here:

[image: XEROX Parc street sign]

I tried to google the words people use for this sign, but found nothing but "a sign".

Comment: A graphic designer might tell you that’s a [**wordmark**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordmark "Wikipedia") rather than a [**logo**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo "Wikipedia"), but either way I don’t know of any specific name for that type of sign.

Comment: @BrianNixon: A wordmark is a kind of logo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [sign business](http://www.hardmansigns.com/monument-signs.aspx), these are called *[monument signs](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=define%3a%20monument%20signs&hl=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=17mvT9zJIenM2gWK35XpCA&ved=0CHcQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=705#hl=en&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=monument%20signs&oq=monument%20signs&aq=f&aqi=g2g-m8&aql=1&gs_l=img.3..0l2j0i5l8.9891.12163.0.12467.14.14.0.0.0.0.131.1382.9j5.14.0.cish.1.0.0.K66Wzk57QBk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=13d31e2f5080bc67&biw=1280&bih=705)*.

Comment: If placed at the entrance to a business, city, or subdivision, they are more specifically called [entrance monument signs.](http://www.google.com/search?q=entrance+monument+signs&hl=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=A3qwT9DTN4P00gGdoqi7DA&ved=0CKUBELAE&biw=1267&bih=607)